# CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type

Tags: php, magento, runtime-error, magento-1.9

[image]

We developed a magento extension and it seems to be working just fine but suddenly a couple of customers contacted us stating that they get an error when trying to install our extension by uploading *.tgz package through magento connect manager.

The error in the console says:

> CONNECT ERROR: Unsupported resource type

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30820/connect-error-unknown-resource-type

Comment: try this : http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php